# How precise is "last seen X minutes ago"? And what counts as "seen"?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, users, last-seen

I was wondering how precise the indication is that a user was last seen X minutes ago.

And which actions would be required for a user to be "seen"? If he had a question page open in his browser, and it updated automatically to show e.g. a change in rep or the "1 new answer to this question" message, would that be considered as the user being seen? Or would he need to actively interact with the page (voting, commenting, reloading, following a link...) to be seen?

This may seem like a strange or futile question, but sometimes it's useful to know whether a user has already seen a certain comment or answer, e.g. to know whether he's responsive to comments asking to clarify his question.

Comment: I am not sure how it's calculated... But it won't indicate that the user saw an answer or comment. It'll just mean that the user was active at that time. If the user has 2 tabs, he might interact on the second one and miss updates on the first.

Comment: The clearest signal that someone has... "seen" your comment or answer is if they've responded to it or acted upon it.

Comment: @m69 I have 2 tabs open. You post a comment now, on tab #1. I don't see it. I go to tab #2 and post on tab #2. The system says I was seen after your comment. I still haven't seen your comment. It's unreliable as a metric. Active is active somewhere on the site. It doesn't mean I have seen everything on the site at that time.

Comment: I use the information to determine if an account is effectively dead.

Comment: @Patrice I'm sure the OP is referring to comments or answers that the user gets notifications about (i.e., comments/answers on the user's post or comments with `@user`). If the user has been "active" _--let's say--_ an hour+ after that kind of a comment or answer was posted, odds are, he most likely saw the notification and either opened or ignored it. That's, of course, assuming that "Last seen" means "has been active on the site" which doesn't seem to be the case based on Shog9's answer.

Comment: @Ahmed I routinely leave notifications unseen, for various reasons. you can of course make that assumption if you want. But it's just that: an assumption. As KevinB said, short of the user acting on whatever is in the comment/answer, you can never be certain. Which is why I say it's unreliable.

Comment: I've visited my own profile and it has said that I've not been seen for several minutes, even after I move off the webpage and circle back; some sites report seeing me a couple of seconds ago - so, each site has a different priority and list of outstanding tasks affecting the scheduling. --- It's the same thing for some users: You come back and there are several Notifications, you look at the first one and someone kindly explains that you missed a key point in your answer. You might spend an hour improving that question and run out of spare time to view all the remaining Notifications.

Comment: At this very moment last seen doesn't even exist for anyone. I don't know when it got turned off but I'm pretty sure I last saw last seen last night.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Any request you make to the site as a logged-in user *can* count as "seen". If it's been at least 15 minutes since the last time you were "seen", then the date is updated; otherwise, it isn't.

The date shown on your profile corresponds to the LastAccessDate column on the Users table in the data dump or Data Explorer.

Since any site access counts, it's not terribly useful as a means of determining whether a given user has seen something specific; at best you can know that they *might* have seen it should the date be later than the creation of the thing you wanted them to see.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you can be almost sure that they *haven't* seen the new response yet.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz what about app or email notifications?